# Scala + Play + Intellij IDEA Issue

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator, typesafe-stack

I was getting below error when I was making new Scala + Play project using activator. I am using standard activator method to generate Intellij Idea support for project but every time I was facing below issue.

I dont know how to resolve below issue. Please help,

## #

The project 'play-scala-intro' has an older format and will be converted. You may not be able to open the project with earlier versions of IntelliJ IDEA. Details...

Old versions of project files will be saved to: 'E:\Personal\Scala Workspace\play-scala-intro\projectFilesBackup'

## #

Comment: Idea 14 uses a new project structure which is different from what generated by `sbt-idea-plugin`. To use with idea, just create your activator project and click `file -> open` in `Idea` then select your project root directory. Use options `Auto import` and `download sources`. And you are done. Don't select the `build.sbt` file, select the root directory of project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolbved.  As **Sarvesh Kumar Singh** mentioned I have created activator project and open that project in In Intellij IDEA and used **options Auto import and download sources**.

Above option resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

this problem probably happened when you use activator's command idea or git (you pull your collaborator's settings) . I have a same problem (also auto-complete doesn't work for my company's class ). I remove .setting , .idea , and every thing start with dot. next open project from Intellij and config my project.

this solve my problem I hope could help you ,too.